# how to solve in react Cannot set properties of null (setting 'inner HTML')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  
const fun=()=>{
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML='Hello world'
}
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={fun()}>click</button>
      <p id="id"></p>
    </>
  );
}
```

how to resolve the error in react? not in JavaScript. If we are not use inner HTML instead of that what to use in that field?

Comment: You should not be doing this in a React app. Use the state to store the value to display. Changing display content  with innerHTML will be lost when next render occurs

Comment: It's not recommended to use innerHtml, but if you really need to you would have to call dangerouslysetinnerhtml https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you are calling `fun` **immediately** and then assigning its return value (`undefined`) to `onClick`.

To go about this the way you are trying, you need to assign the function itself.

```
onClick={fun}
```

---

However, **direct DOM manipulation runs counter to the way React is designed to work**.

Your changes are likely to get wiped out if anything triggers a re-render.

React is designed to be **data driven**. To change the DOM you should change the data and let React pull it through to the DOM itself.

You should make use of **state** to track the data.

```
export default function DropDown() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const fun = useCallback(() => setOpen(open => !open), []);
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={fun}>click</button>
    {open && (<p>Hello, world</p>)
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, using the State Hook

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Your code should be

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState('Hello world');
  const onChange = () => {
    setGreeting('New greeting')
  }

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={onChange}>click</button>
      <p id="id">{greeting}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are calling the `fun` function instead of binding it to the click.

It should be : `<button onClick={fun}>click</button>`

See this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-mahavira-jgbm6?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
 const [text,setText] useState('');

const fun=()=>{
  setText('Hello world')
}
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={fun}>click</button>
      <p id="id">{text}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Use state. Using innerHTML is not recommended.
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you would do something like that in React.
In most cases, if you are working in React and find yourself manipulating the DOM (`document.getElementById('id').innerHTML`) chances are you are doing it in the "wrong" way and you should double-check your work.

In this case, you should have something like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function DropDown() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState();
  const fun = () => {
    setContent('Hello World!')
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={fun}>click</button>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```